# Open external app Ionic 2

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, ionic2

How to open an external app installed in a mobile using Ionic 2 framework?
I do not find any plugins in ionic-native.
I tried to use com.lampa.startapp in ionic2 which I was using in ionic1.
But `windows.plugins` always returns undefined.

Comment: Maybe this one is relevant. It's Ionic's plugin for deeplinking https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-deeplinks and here is their blog about the plugin which may help you identify if it is useful or not http://blog.ionic.io/deeplinking-in-ionic-apps/

Comment: Have you found any solution. I am also looking for this solution.

Comment: declare var cordova: any did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Cordova plugin `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser`, go through installations using [Ionic In App Browser](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser/).

There is detailed description of same described in [Ionic forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-opening-external-app/77932/3).

```
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';

constructor(public appBrowser: InAppBrowser) { }

// in some function
this.appBrowser.create('vnd.youtube://', '_system'); // Youtube
this.appBrowser.create('twitter://user?screen_name=', '_system');
```